# Update tab bar Item badge in iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem, badge

In my iOS application I have 2 tab bar items called `1tab` and `2tab`.

Now, `1tab` is selected, so `1tab`'s view controller is loaded.

`2tab`'s view controller isn't loaded, but I still want to push and mark `2tab` with a "New" badge.

How can I control the view controller of the other tab bar items that is not loaded?

Comment: I shortened the text a bit and tried to explain it in better english. Hopefully it still is a correct question? :)

Comment: Why does your view controller need to be loaded to update the badge?